# How do I count the number of times a function is called?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my code, what I am trying to do is to apply a function written by me to a numpy array column-wisely. To know the progress of the program, I want to do similar thing as I can do in for loop with if `i % 100 == 0: print i`

```
from sklearn.mixture import GMM

gmm = GMM(n_components=2)

def getFunc(x):
    print 1
    return gmm.fit_predict(np.expand_dims(x,axis=1))

newX = np.apply_along_axis(getFunc, 0, inputX)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try writing a decorator for your function.

```
from functools import wraps
from sklearn.mixture import GMM

gmm = GMM(n_components=2)

def log_every(n):
    def decorator(fn)
        counter = 0
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            counter += 1
            if counter % n == 0:
                print(n)
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@log_every(100)
def getFunc(x):
    return gmm.fit_predict(np.expand_dims(x,axis=1))

newX = np.apply_along_axis(getFunc, 0, inputX)
```

But, as @MarcusMüller points out, performance would probably suffer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such facility – in fact, there can't be, because `apply_along_axis` is a monolithic call (and that's a good thing, for performance reasons) that mostly happens in C/CPython. There's no facility to communicate the amount of already "processed" items back to python – in fact, when considering the Global Interpreter Lock, I don't even see how that could even happen.

So, no, this won't work, unless your `getFunc` updates a `global` counter – which might or might not be a good idea, considering that it's actually pretty close to being a lambda (you'll probably get a speed improvement if you use `lambda x: gmm.fit_predict(np.expand_dims(x, axis=1))` instead of `getFunc`, or just use `np.vectorize`!).

Comment: Calling a lambda isn't any faster than calling the equivalent function created using `def`.

Comment: @PM2Ring isn't it so that having a function leads to having locals which leads to having to garbage collection/deconstruction? Also, notice the `print 1` I tried to avoid (IO being relatively slow).

Comment: Sure, printing will certainly slow down the execution. I only posted my previous comment because your last paragraph (sort of) implies that using a lambda would be faster than a regular `def` function, and that's not the case, assuming the lambda and the regular function contain the same code.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is pure Python.  It doesn't speed up the code; neither does `np.vectorize`.

Answer (score 1):

A `global` counter should work, so would a mutable counter

```
Out[1471]: array([12, 15, 18, 21])
In [1472]: A=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [1473]: def foo(x):
      ...:     counter[0] +=1
      ...:     print(counter)
      ...:     return sum(x)
      ...: 
In [1474]: counter=[0]
In [1475]: np.apply_along_axis(foo,0,A)
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
Out[1475]: array([12, 15, 18, 21])
```

Note that in this case `apply_along_axis` is

```
In [1476]: [sum(col) for col in A.T]
Out[1476]: [12, 15, 18, 21]
In [1477]: A.sum(axis=0)
Out[1477]: array([12, 15, 18, 21])
```

Why are you using `apply_along_axis`?  What's the dimension of `inputX`?

In a 2d case, `apply_along_axis` is basically:

```
[sum(A[(slice(None),i)]) for i in range(A.shape[1])]
```

If `A` is higher dimensioned, it takes care of iterating on `(slice(None),i,j...)` for all `i,j...`.  But there are other ways of generating those indices.  It provides convenience, not speed or functionality.